# Send large object over network in python

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm looking for a ready-to-use solution to send large pickled objects (1MB-1GB) over network and Internet, back-and-forth between a server and several clients.

I've seen solutions with sockets, yet it is unclear to me which solutions are optimal for transfer over fast networks, and how reliable they are. A typical example I would encounter would be sending ~100Mb objects between US and Europe over near-gigabit Internet.

Comment: You could consider using one of several Async I/O frameworks and lirbaries for this. e.g: [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits)

Comment: Some other good libraries/frameworks: [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) [AsyncIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) (*Python 3+*)

Comment: Have you also considered compressing your objects as well? Then trying to send the data? You could try UDP but it may be inconsistent and not meet your requirements. Otherwise, try TCP.

Comment: The sizes are for compressed objects.

Comment: multiprocessing uses pickle to serialize objects. Maybe you can use that. It is in the standard library. Also, you can use Pyro. Do you have any reliability constraints?

Comment: Pickle is reliable enough for me. The problem is transferring the data across the Internet. For that I want 99.9% reliability, but not really 100%.